# jQuery not: selector with OR

Tags: jquery, css

I have 3 CSS classes a, b, c

I would like to select all elements which are in class 'a' but not in any of 'b' or 'c'
For example

```
class="a" <- select
class="anyThing" <- do not select
class="a anyThing" <- select
class="a b" <- do not select
class="a c" <- do not select
class="a anything c" <- do not select
```

Here is what I am trying without success:

```
$('.a:not(.b .c)')...
```

What am I missing?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried $('.a:not(.b):not(.c)') ?

Comment: @Julien Thanks. Please post as answer, and I will mark it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) within the [:not-selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

```
$('.a:not(.b, .c)')...
```

Comment: +1 This is the solution you want OP - [**JsFiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/vwr4964g/)

Answer (score 1):

Use like this:

```
$('.a').not('.a.b,.a.c')
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lofwn25x/)

You may also use $('.a').not('.a,.b') but there's different.

Check difference here in the fiddles: [fiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/Lofwn25x/1/) | 
[fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/Lofwn25x/2/)

So, I think you would choose 1 method.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the dot.

Answer (score 1):

This will works perfectly:

```
$('.a:not(.b,.c)')...
```